# Progressbar ao solicitar download de um arquivo com FileResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Como posso exibir uma progressbar enquanto o servidor processa o retorno de um FileResult?

Tentei realizar a operação com Ajax, mas não é possível realizar o download de um arquivo via ajax sem redireciona-lo (utilizando um `window.location.href`) para a action que retorna o FileResult.

Answer (score 1):

Olá.
Acredito que de forma assíncrona resolveria.

1. Abra uma thread no servidor e baixe o arquivo para um diretório temporário
2. Faça o download controlando o progresso. Veja: http://devtoolshed.com/content/c-download-file-progress-bar
3. No cliente, pergunte ao servidor qual o percentual de progresso e atualize sua progressbar.
4. Faça o download do arquivo!

Abs.